# occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code1:17 AM 10/21/2016

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Here i have a Query Like  **'select * from Employees where DataofJoin= '2001-01-01 00:00:00.000';** I convert this query into linq as

```
public JsonResult Dif(int Date = 0, int Month = 0, int Year = 0)
{
var date = new DateTime(Year, Month, Date);

            var x = (from n in db.Employees
                     where n.DataofBirth == date
                     select n).First();
return new JsonResult { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
```

But whenever i try to enter the date Like as shown in sql query its takes date Like **'{1/1/0001 12:00:00 Am}'**
And its through Error Like   occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code1:17 AM 10/21/2016

Comment: Those defaults makes no sense. You cannot create a Date when year or month or day is zero.

Comment: no Bro Here all these r comming from DropdownLst

Comment: And what values are coming here? Did you try to debug this code?

Comment: here im trying to insert Date as 1/1/2016 its comming in query after comming into quey its convert ino  {1/1/0001 12:00:00 Am} I think due to this im getting error

Comment: If you execute `Dif(1, 1, 2016)` you can't possibly get a query with `1/1/0001`, so which call gives rise to the exception?